# Using order details on success page multiple times

Tags: magento2.3, order-success-page

I would like to be able to bring the order specifics into variables so I can reuse for various tracking apps on the success page. I'm still learning php with some knowledge of magento so appreciate detailed help if possible.

Example details I'll need to output:

- order id
- sku
- ean
- brand
- product name
- quantity
- grandTotal

Magento 2.3

Cheers in advance
Andy

Comment: you want in magento 2 or 1 ?

Comment: Yes, that would help wouldn't it :) Version 2.3.4